# If $q$ is a limit point of $V$, where $V$ is a subset of some metric space, can $q$ be outside of $V$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Definition of a Limit Point :** A point $p$ is a limit point of a set $E$ if *every* neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q \neq p$ such that $q \in E$. In this definition $E$ is a subset of a metric space

Now my question is: *If $q$ is a limit point of $V$, where $V$ is a subset of some metric space, can $q$ be outside of $V$?*

I would think so, as if we let $V = E^c$, then the boundary points of $E$ would be limit points of $V$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for a concrete example, consider $B(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, the open ball of radius $1$.  The limit points of this make up a set $\overline{B}(0,1)$, the closed ball of radius $1$.  We have that:
$$\overline{B}(0,1)\setminus B(0,1) = \left\lbrace x\in\mathbb R^n\mid d(x,0) = 1\right\rbrace$$
Note that if it is assumed $V$ is closed, $q$ can no longer be outside of $V$. One characterization of a closed set is that it contains all of its limit points.  But, for any open set $V$, we can just look at $\overline{V}\setminus V$ to find limit points of $V$ that aren't contained in $V$.